# Correct syntax for multiple if not + OR in Jinja2 if statement

Tags: if-statement, jinja2, statements

I want to do X if my asnitem.asn is **neither one of the values** I gave.

What I thought would work:

```
{%- if not asnitem.asn == 45102 or if not asnitem.asn == 24429 or if not asnitem.asn == 132203 %}
```

But that just gives me a syntax error.
So I also tried:

```
{%- (if not asnitem.asn == 45102) or (if not asnitem.asn == 24429) or (if not asnitem.asn == 132203) %}
```

But that also does not work. So im currently confused how to do **multiple or's** in a Jinja2 if statemements. Thanks to everyone who gives a answer.
Also if there is a way better way to do something like this, please tell me. Maybe something like?:

```
{%- if not asnitem.asn == 45102 || 24429 || 132203 %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `in` logical operator should help you in this case. Try this sample:

```
{%- if not asnitem.asn in [45102, 24429, 132203] %}
```

`in` operator here checks presence of the *left-hand* value (`asnitem.asn`) in the *right-hand* list (`[45102, 24429, 132203]`). And `not` inverts the result of the check.